# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel with Variable/Responsive Number of Elements Shown depending on browser size

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using version v3.1.1 of Twitter Bootstrap to make a carousel on my website. **I would like to be able to adjust the number of items shown in the carousel depending on the size of the browser/device which people are accessing the site.** For example, if I have 15 items, and the the browser is larger, go through 3 sets of 5 items visible, if smaller, show 5 sets of 3 visible at a time, and if mobile, show 15 sets of 1 visible item... It seems so simple and  a common request... but I can't find it on Stack Overflow or by Googling.

The items are of defined dimensions, and you can assume they're pretty much like this:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
```

To give more detail, the items in the carousels are meant to be "linked previews" invited people to click on the items to find more info about them, and I have multiple carousels on the page displaying items of different types (much like youtube or netflix has on their websites), so it's not really appropriate for me to show a constant amount of items per page and adjust each item's height/width/margins in response to changing browser dimensions. Since I don't want to adjust their dimensions, I'm forced to adjust the number of items visible.

The number of total objects in the set can be small (<10) or larger (100's), but it will dynamically grow over time. The number of items visible at a time will likely range between 1-6.

Sample code for the bootstrap carousel can be found here: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/twitter-bootstrap-101-the-carousel--webdesign-7442

I've tried the following:

Bootstrap Carousel - I've got it set-up properly, looks and behaives like a carousel. Rotates as needed, but when I shrink the browser the margins get eaten up, and all the visible items end up overlapping on one another.

Owl Carousel V2.0.0-beta.2.4 beta- Couldn't get it set-up properly. All the items just ended up as a column regardless of what number I set to the right of "items" below:

```
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                loop:true,
                margin:10,
                nav:true,
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:1
                    },
                    600:{
                        items:3
                    },
                    1000:{
                        items:5
                    }
                }
            })
```

I've also tried the responsive carousel here: http://basilio.github.io/responsiveCarousel/.  I was able to set it up as a carousel and set the default number of items visible, but couldn't figure out to modulate that in response to browser size. I tried to inspect the author's own code behind his "Example carousels"  (because the ones on his site do what I want) but to no avail.

When I tried any the bootply samples in the following two links, I couldn't find any samples with multiple items in a carousel and which were responsive.

(All samples here) http://www.bootply.com/like/carousel+responsive
(First ~15 samples here) http://www.bootply.com/like/carousel

Lastly, I tried BX Slider (http://bxslider.com/) and that worked like a charm...mostly. I got the Carousel set up and it adjusted to my minSlides when I made the browser narrow... only issue was that sometimes it would show a fraction of the image, but that seems to be how it's programmed and I'm not sure it's such a bad thing. This is what I'm using now.

Ultimately, I'm not really a fan of Bootstrap's html grammar where I have to cut up my total set of items into smaller sets as opposed to the other ones where I can just dump al the items in a div container and have javascript cut up the set as needed). I'm just looking to minimize the number of extra css and js files attached to the site. As I'm using bootstrap for the overall layout, that means looking for a bootstrap solution.

Comment: I realize this isn't using bootstrap, but have you checked out Owl carousel? Great slider where you can choose the amount of slides to display based on the screen size. http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far? Is there a reason that your carousel should show fewer items to those folks using smaller screens? Is it a perception about speed, or do some of the items in the carousel not apply to mobile users?

Comment: @JasonAller - I've updated my original post to address your question.

Comment: @dodgerogers747 - I have tried the Owl carousel but couldn't get it set up properly. I'm looking to reduce the number of css/js files hanging on the site so I'd like to be able to do it in bootstrap.